# How to create directories in PHP that can actually be used (mkdir() and apache problem)?

Tags: php, apache, file, exec, mkdir

I have literally spent days searching for a solution to this problem. PHP's mkdir() function is creating directories with owner/group: apache:apache. There is no way I can work in this directory via FTP because the file doesn't belong to me.

How in the world am I supposed to create directories and manage files with PHP if the user is always set to apache?

Is there a workaround? Should I create directories via exec() or system() ?

Any help is appreciated.

tundoopani

Comment: You should try to ask it on http://serverfault.com/, tons of admins there, they'll explain you how to adapt the ftp server, or the php-apache user to make the two system work together. That's something your application cannot manage entirely, it's an admin task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving cross-user access problems between a PHP installation and another sub-system (in this case, FTP) usually involves one of two solutions: running both sub-systems as the same user, or putting both users in a common group.

In any case, the FTP protocol lets you create directories. Why not create them from your FTP client?

Comment: a directory is created for each user and so PHP must be used. I have tried using exec() to create the directories as well.

Comment: Is the website creating user directories in response to a signup process? In that case I would be looking at how the FTP server implements virtual users and hook into that mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can [chown()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) them ( Changes file owner)

however note that

> Only the superuser may change the owner of a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's:

```
chown(string $filename, mixed $user);
```

You can just pass in a director instead of a file as $filename, and your username into $user.

Comment: I've heard many bad things about chown() due to some security issue. Also only a superuser can process that. I'll try it at least and see what happens though.

Comment: No, don't do that. Allowing Apache to run commands via sudo is a massive security risk.

Comment: Even if you only allow it access to chown in a specific directory?